# Nested testcases in Scalatest AsyncFlatSpec

Tags: scala, scalatest

I was using wordspec for asserting following scenario

```
case class Assertion(expected:Any, actual:Any)
case class TestCases(name:String, assertions:List[Assertions])
val testCases = List[TestCases]

"Testcases" should {
  testCases.foreach(testCase =>{
    s"${testCase.name}" should {
      testCase.assertions.foreach(assertion=>{
        assert(assertion.expected == assertion.actual)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Now things have changed a bit, the testcases are now a `Future[List[Assertion]] instead of List[Assertion].`
I tried using AsyncFlatSpec but I'm having problems with nested test cases as you can see above, when the test runs with nested test cases it says empty test suite..

```
val testCasesFuture = Future[List[TestCases]]

behavior of "Testcases"
testCasesFuture.foreach(testCases =>{
   testCases.foreach(testCase =>{
      it should s"${testCase.name}" in {
        testCase.assertions.foreach(assertion=>{
          assert(assertion.expected == assertion.actual)
      })
    }
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending alot of time debugging I finally found an answer, I moved the Future to inside of Assertion and that solved the problem.. Here's code snippet to understand better

```
import org.scalatest.AsyncWordSpec

import scala.concurrent.Future

class FutureSpec extends AsyncWordSpec {
  case class Assert(expected: Any, actual: Any)
  case class Assertion(name: String, assert: Future[Assert])
  case class TestCase(name: String, assertion: List[Assertion])
  val testCases = List(TestCase("sample", List(Assertion("first", Future(Assert(1, 1))))))

  "TestCase" should {
    testCases.foreach { testCase =>
      {
        testCase.name should {
          testCase.assertion.foreach(assertion => {
            assertion.name in {
              assertion.assert.map(a => assert(a.expected == a.actual))
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```